# Is it consistent that $2^{(\cdot)}$ is "surjective" on the class of uncountable ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

$\newcommand{\Z}{{\sf (ZFC)}}$

It is consistent in $\Z$ that there is an uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ such that for no cardinal $\lambda$ we have $2^\lambda = \kappa$: Take any model in which $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$, and $\kappa = \aleph_1$.

Is there a model in $\Z$ such that for every cardinal $\kappa > \aleph_0$ there is a cardinal $\lambda$ such that $2^\lambda = \kappa$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By Konig's lemma $cf(2^\kappa)  > \kappa,$ so for example $\aleph_\omega$ can never be of the form $2^\kappa$ for any $\kappa.$

Comment: You don't even need Kőnig's theorem to answer this question. If $\aleph_\omega$ is in the range of the exponential function, then $\aleph_\omega=2^{\aleph_n}$ for some $n\lt\omega$, so at most $n$ of the infinite cardinals below $\aleph_\omega$ can be in the range of the exponential function.

Comment: @bof Interesting observation!

Comment: Note also that one doesn't even need the axiom of choice, since if $\aleph_\omega$ is the size of $P(X)$, then $X$ is well-orderable, hence $\aleph_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Note that the result you used  is generally called König's *theorem* (as  in @bof's comment). König's *lemma* is the one about paths through finitely branching trees.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Forgive the pedantry but I believe the Hungarian mathematician Kőnig spelled his German surname with a Hungarian ő (as in Erdős). That's the phonetic spelling in Hungarian, which always distinguishes between long and short vowels.

Comment: @bof I'm aware oof the difference between Hungarian  and German, and I'd use \H fir the former in TeX. But I don't know  how to produce the Hungarian version in a comment here. S I'm stuck not only with König but also Erdös.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I  don't know how to produce ő from the keyboard so I copy and paste.